# Empty bash command line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I am looking for a way to delete the currently entered command line without wasting seconds on the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key.

For example I scrolled the bash history and have a long command line that would execute when I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
~$ aptitude search openssl | grep dev
```

But now I decide that I do not want to execute this command. Can I get an empty prompt fast without deleting the whole line with <kbd>Backspace</kbd>? On the Windows **cmd** you can just press <kbd>Escape</kbd> and it is gone. This behavior would be what I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> will empty the current line.

It's the default **kill** character on most terminals and it erases the current line (from the cursor to its beginning). The [**stty**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html) command can be used to get or set its value.

```
[dave@hal9000 ~]$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 23; columns 75; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?;
eol2 = M-^?; swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
...
[dave@hal9000 ~]$ stty kill ^T # Set it to Ctrl-T
```

Be the way, `werase` stands for word erase, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> erases the word on the left of the cursor.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Ctrl-u deletes all characters before the cursor position.

Comment: @vobject: If your cursor is within the line, Ctrl-u then Ctrl-k (or vice-versa) will get it all.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to cancel the command you're entering and go back to a bare prompt.

This is a common key in unix text mode applications:

- in non-interactive programs, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> usually stops the program altogether and goes back to a shell prompt;
- in interactive programs that execute one command at a time (such as shells), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> usually returns to the main command prompt.